# How to get pem file for AWS Autoscaling launched instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, terraform

I have a `Terraform` script that launches `VPC`, subnets, database, autoscaling and some other stuff. Autoscaling uses default Windows Server 2012 R2 images to launch new instances (including the initial ones). Every instance is executing `Chef` install after launch. I need to log into the instance so i can confirm that `Chef` is installed but i dont have any `.pem` keys. How do i launch an instance with `Autoscaling` and `launch_configuration` and output `.pem` file so i can login afterwards?
Here is my autoscaling part of the script:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asgPrimary" {
  depends_on = ["aws_launch_configuration.primary"]
  availability_zones        = ["${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]}"]
  name                      = "TerraformASGPrimary"
  max_size                  = 1
  min_size                  = 1
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = "0"
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  desired_capacity          = 1
  force_delete              = false
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = "0"
  vpc_zone_identifier = ["${aws_subnet.private_primary.id}"]
  #placement_group           = "${aws_placement_group.test.id}"
  launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.primary.name}"
  load_balancers = ["${aws_elb.elb.name}"]
}
```

and this is my launch configuration:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "primary" {
  depends_on = ["aws_subnet.primary"]
  name          = "web_config_primary"
  image_id      = "${data.aws_ami.amazon_windows_2012R2.id}"
  instance_type = "${var.ami_type}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.primary.id}"]
  user_data = "${template_file.user_data.rendered}"
}
```

I need to avoid using Amazon `CLI` or the webpage itself - the point is all that to be automated for reusing in all my other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.pem` files used to RDS/SSH into an EC2 instance are not generated during launch of an EC2 instance. It may appear like this when using the AWS Management Console, but in actuality, the Key Pair is generated first, and then that Key Pair is assigned to the EC2 instance during launch.

To get your `.pem` file, first:

1. Generate a new Key Pair. See [Amazon EC2 Key Pairs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html). When you do this, you will be able to download the `.pem` file.
2. Assign that Key Pair to your Auto Scaling Group's launch configuration using the `key_name` argument.

Here's an example:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "primary" {
  depends_on = ["aws_subnet.primary"]
  name          = "web_config_primary"
  image_id      = "${data.aws_ami.amazon_windows_2012R2.id}"
  instance_type = "${var.ami_type}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.primary.id}"]
  user_data = "${template_file.user_data.rendered}",
  key_name = "my-key-pair"
}
```

See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#key_name